# Is "present perfect" more common with special verbs?

Tags: present-perfect

I wrote this sentence

> We **have implemented** the proposed system as a visual tool for wrapper generation.

Maybe I could say:

> We **implemented** the proposed system as a visual tool for wrapper generation.

Because I feel, maybe "implementation" is not something that needs to be continued to the present.

Are there some rules here?

Answer (score 1):

The perfect does not necessarily imply that the action of its lexical verb continues into the present; with a telic verb (one which has a goal or endpoint 'built in' to its sense) it implies a current state which arose from the action of the lexical verb.

Whether you employ a simple past or a present perfect depends on your discourse context.